# How to prevent transitionend event being run twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a small app that animates sections in and out using CSS3 adding and removing `.is-active` at one point I need to remove `.is-active` from the element `.resulting-page` then on `transitionend` add `.is-active` back on to the element as I need to make a quick z-index update, doing this however seems to trigger the code inside the `transitionend` function twice. Was wondering if anyone can advise on how to fix this?

**JS**

```
$('.resulting-page').removeClass('is-active').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function () {              
      $('.search-page').removeClass('tier3-override');
      $(this).addClass('is-active');
      console.log('this ran');  
});
```

**JS Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/aagTH/16/

Comment: before adding the last class simply turn off the event and re-bind it afterwards? :)

Comment: hey @Alex do stop the event inside the on event or how do i structure the code?

Comment: i dont quite get what the problem is/ is happening that shall not happen twice, but would a simple variable check work out for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/aagTH/17/

Comment: the problem is, if you click an Entry Link on main slide, then click the Search Subpage Link in main navigation, then click an Entry Link on Search Page then click the Back button on the results page that page slides down and up like the event is firing twice?

Comment: @styler seems to be an error in your logic.  At some point, `check` should be set to `true` before the Resulting Page appears, but that never happens.  Since it's false, you immediately add back the `is-active` class

Comment: ok so the check variable is definitely required it just needs to set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Modernizr to get the browser specific transitionend. Chrome will trigger on transitionend and webkitTransitionEnd if both applied.

```
var transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',  // Saf 6, Android Browser
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',           // only for FF < 15
        'transition': 'transitionend'               // IE10, Opera, Chrome, FF 15+, Saf 7+
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('transition')];

return transEndEventName;
```